# General case of non-trival recursive probablility estimation

Tags: probability

Consider a domain registrar that can send email to clients if they have a domain expiring in the next 60 days. Clients that have a single domain should see 305 days of no mail in their inbox:

```
365 - 60 = 305
```

**On average, how many no-mail days would a user with `N` domains enjoy?**

The case for 2 domains is rather involved though I think that I got it:

```
Case 1: No-mail periods do not overlap: 365 - 60 - 60 = 245
Case 2: No-mail periods overlap: 245 + (average period between dates) = 245 + (60/2) = 275
Total:  (365-60)/365 ( 245 ) + 60/365 * ( 275 ) ~ 249
```

To generalize this any further, I would reach for Python and do something recursive and ugly. **How would a statician write this? How would a statician solve it for `N=6`?**

This is not homework, rather something that I challenged myself with after looking in my inbox this morning.

Comment: The mathematician within me wants to solve it in a nice probabilistic way, but, I don't know how to. Btw., I'm not sure about your average 249 days for the N=2 case. As the year is cyclic, I'd say the days with no period overlap are 246 and, therefore, the average days without mail are ~ 254.9.

Comment: @JonNagra: Let's not forget that policy change could make 60 days change to 90, and I understand that Elon Musk's time estimates indicate that he uses a 687-day calendar!